# Sorting and validating a date (YYMMDD) in struct

Tags: c++, validation, sorting, date, struct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct student{
    int ID;           // ID
    string firstname; // first name
    string lastname;  // last name
    int date;         // YYMMDD
};

bool is_num(const string &s);
void input_year(student &students);
int length_of_int(int input);

int main(){
    student students[100];
    int amount_of_students;
    cin >> amount_of_students;
    for(int i = 0; i < amount_of_students; i++){
        cout << "Enter student's ID" << endl;
        cin >> students[i].ID;
        cout << "Enter student's first name" << endl;
        cin >> students[i].firstname;
        cout << "Enter student's last name" << endl;
        cin >> students[i].lastname;
        cout << "Enter student's date of birth" << endl;
        input_year(students[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void input_year(student &students){
    while(true){
        string input;
        cin >> input;
        if(is_num(input)){
            students.date = atoi(input.c_str());
            if(length_of_int(students.date) != 6){
                cout << "Error, try again." << endl;
            }
            else{
                if()
                break;
            }
        }
        else{
            cout << "Error, try again." << endl;
        }
    }
}

bool is_num(const string &s){
    string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while(it != s.end() && isdigit(*it)){
        ++it;
    }
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}

int length_of_int(int input){
    int length = 0;
    while(input > 0){
        length++;
        input /= 10;
    }
    return length;
}
```

I have the following code, and I want to sort the array (students[100]) of the struct by DATE and validate the input of date as well.

What I do right now is validate it's 6 characters and a number. However, I'd like to validate it also to check if it's a valid date (01-12 months, 01-30 days).

As for the year, I know there is a possible problem, like:
501022 could mean both 1950 and 2050, but there is a special case for this one.

If the year is from 50-99, it refers to 19xx, if it's from 00-14, it refers to 20xx.

I need a validation for that and a method to sort it either in ascending or descending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort an Array you could use qsort() for example (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/). It would look like the following:

Functioncall:

```
qsort (students, amount_of_students, sizeof(student), func_ptr);
```

compar-function:

```
typedef int (*compar)(const void*,const void*);
compar func_ptr;

int sort_ascending (const void* student1, cont void* student2)
{
  long value1=student1->date; 
  long value2=student2->date;

  if(value1 < 150000) 
  { value1 += 20000000;} else { value1 += 19000000;}
  if(value2 <150000)
  { value2 += 20000000;} else { value2 += 19000000;}
  return value1 - value2;
}
```

For sort_descending() you have to switch value1 and value2.

edit:
included

> If the year is from 50-99, it refers to 19xx, if it's from 00-14, it refers to 20xx.

Hint: I would use long instead of int for the Date (int has 2 or 4 or 8 Byte depending on the system)

Comment: Does it sort the int only? Or does it effectively sort the dates (along with year/month/day)?

Comment: It sorts the dates.First step is to expand YYMMDD to YYYYMMDD. with YYYYMMDD a "younger" date will have a higher integer value (or a higher long value) than the "older" date. I'm not absolutely sure if the return statement is correct for sort_ascending. But in fact you just have to switch value1 and value2 in the return statement to change the sort sequence.

Answer (score 1):

First of a few general hints.

1. Storing the data as an int seems wrong. A date is not a number! It does not behave like a number. And there are many other ways to display a date than YYMMDD. The 501022 is a real problem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem
2. `student students[100];` could be done a lot better and safer. Why use memory for 100 students if you only have 10? Why should your program blow up when there is 101 students? 
   There is no need for that. read up on std::vector and other containers int the standard library. It will make your code a lot safer!

As for your actual question, DD should come out with the modulus operator %

`a%b` gives the remainder a's division with b. so

```
11 % 5 = 1
4 % 2 = 0
1311 % 100 = 11
```

This way you can check the day. I'm sure you can work out how to check the month after that :-)

For sorting, you can use qsort(). See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort and http://cplus.about.com/od/learningc/ss/pointers2_8.htm or http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-function-of-qsort-in-c/

the comparison function can just directly compare the student.date. Here you get a freeride because the date is an int. so you can compare student a and b directly

```
if (a.date == b.date) {
```

Well... except for that year 2000 issue...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am doing this exercise for college and it's specified that the date should be of type `int`. As for the year-2000 problem, I know about it, and I've already talked to the professor and he told me to take years from 50-99 as 19xx and years from 00-14 as 20xx. As for the [100], it's because the specifications of maximum 100 elements, and I'll be sure to include checks for amount_of_students after I solve the sorting.